# How to input egrep result as a variable to awk

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a dataset that looks like the below:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
read1,chr1,Unassigned_NoFeatures,
read2,chr2,Assigned,
read3,chr3,,Assigned
```

What I want to do is to perform `egrep` on the "Assigned" and "Unassigned_NoFeatures" strings and then append them to the read names in the first column. The problem I face is that these strings are not always in the same column but I need to grep them and append them to the first column (per entry).

I tried the approach below to input `egrep` results for each entry in my file and input it as a variable to awk but it did not work.

```
cat my_file.csv | variable=$(egrep -o "Assigned|Unassigned_NoFeatures") | awk -F, '{print $1"_"variable,$2}'
```

The desired output should be as:

```
read1_Unassigned_NoFeatures,chr1
read2_Assigned,chr2
read3_Assigned,chr3
```

How can I make the script work? Thanks

Comment: will you ever have a value in the 3rd column that is *not* `Assigned` or `Unassigned_NoFeatures`? if the answer is `yes` then please update the question with a sample input row (and updated desired result) and an explanation of how that value should be processed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never need `grep` when you're using `awk`. Given your input all you need to do is print the string from the 3rd or 4th field, whichever is not empty, e.g. using any `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR>1{print $1 "_" ($3?$3:$4), $2}' my_file.csv
read1_Unassigned_NoFeatures,chr1
read2_Assigned,chr2
read3_Assigned,chr3
```

or even just, as @jhnc suggested in a comment:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR>1{print $1 "_" $3$4, $2}' my_file.csv
```

but if you actually did need to find strings that match a regexp across a whole line it'd be:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} match($0,/Assigned|Unassigned_NoFeatures/){print $1 "_" substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH), $2}' my_file.csv
```

Comment: `awk -F, 'NR>1{print $1"_"$3$4","$2}' file` ?

Comment: @jhnc nice idea using `$3$4`!.

Answer (score 0):

Whole task might be done using `awk` only as already shown I want to make clear

> How to input(...)variable to awk

If you have variable which you wish to use inside GNU `AWK` you need to ram it using `-v var=val` or `--assign var=val` if you fail to do so, when attempting to use it, GNU `AWK` will assume 0 or empty string, depending on context, consider following example, let say you need to select line having `charnum` characters and `file.txt` is

```
A
BC
DEF
GH
I
```

then

```
charnum=2
awk 'length==charnum' file.txt
```

gives no output, whilst

```
charnum=2
awk -v charnum="$charnum" 'length==charnum' file.txt
```

gives desired output, i.e.

```
BC
GH
```

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*